# Where to find DLL or Documentation for XtraExport?

Tags: c#, export, devexpress

As i googled, it really impressed me that neither a documentation or dll exists for XtraExport (take a look [No Doc Exists for XtraExport](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DB12641.aspx)), and it is still used and needed. My problem is that I wanna do some exportations, and I found an example of DevExpress (*exporting a gridview data to xls file*) for this. That's not working for me, since the DevExpress.XtraExport namespace is not found.

Now the question is, how am I supposed to find it? How am I supposed to work on that example?

Comment: Have you read the link that you posted? It says: "XtraExport isn't a single project or product, there aren't even any dlls called XtraExport. This item was added to support Center to unite together some issues which are connected by export procedures across all DevExpress products."

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to export from an asp.net grid have a look at the DevExpress demo: [Exporting to PDF, XLS and RTF](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Exporting/Exporting.aspx).